# how to convert a string to bool in given data c#

Tags: c#

I have a file that contains `.out` at the end of each line. I have to remove `.out` from every line or replace it with an empty string. I am trying but couldn't get it.

```
string find=".out";
string replace=" ";

var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] { delimeter},StringSplitOptions.None);
if(lineParts.Length > 1)
    lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();

var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 7));
if (!checkIfExist(data))
    lineData.Add(data);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData);

// input samples 
// cpo.gujranwala63201771901PM_Bteq_BT_Bteq_Telenor_User_cpo_gu‌​jranwala_232_102426.‌​out 
// output
// Telenor_User_cpo_gujranwala_232_102426.out
```

I have to replace .out with empty string

Comment: Show some input and the output you get with your current solution

Comment: What does this have to do with converting a string to a bool?

Comment: var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] { delimeter 
     },StringSplitOptions.None);
      if (lineParts.Length > 1) lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
       var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 
      7));
       if (!checkIfExist(data))
              lineData.Add(data);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData)

// input samples 

cpo.gujranwala63201771901PM_Bteq_BT_Bteq_Telenor_User_cpo_gujranwala_232_102426.out
//output 
Telenor_User_cpo_gujranwala_232_102426.out
i have to replace .out with empty string

Comment: Your comment should have been an edit to your question.

Comment: Your edits have not helped at all as it is now totally unclear what it is you are trying to achieve. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\input.txt").Select(l => l.Replace(".out", string.Empty));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", result);
```

Comment: var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] { delimeter },StringSplitOptions.None);
   if (lineParts.Length > 1) lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
   var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 7));
       if (!checkIfExist(data))
              lineData.Add(data);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData)

// input samples 

cpo.gujranwala63201771901PM_Bteq_BT_Bteq_Telenor_User_cpo_gujranwala_232_102426.out
//output sample
Telenor_User_cpo_gujranwala_232_102426.out
i have to replace .out with empty string

Comment: @Adnan Haider My code worked for your original question, but you have edited the question since and this is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

First read all file content. After that make a replacement with `String.Replace`. Then write edited content back to file.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt");

text = text.Replace(".out", " ");

File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);
```